# Only run route animation if navigation was imperative (e.g. click event)

Tags: angular

Is it possible to run route animations conditionally in Angular 14?

I have an Angular PWA with route animations. It works great, however I have a slight issue on iOS Safari. There's a feature in this browser which lets the user swipe back and forth with gestures. I actually like this feature so I do not want to disable it. The problem is that when the user swipes back and forth my route animations becomes glitchy.

So ideally I only want to run my route animations if the navigation was triggered imperatively (e.g. click event).

This is what I have so far. With `prepareRoute` being async no animations run whatsoever.

How could I work around this problem? Any alternative solutions?

```
<main [@routeAnimations]="prepareRoute(outlet)">
  <router-outlet #outlet="outlet"></router-outlet>
</main>

...

public async prepareRoute(outlet: RouterOutlet) {
  const navigation = await lastValueFrom(this.router.events.pipe(filter(event => event instanceof NavigationStart))) as NavigationStart;
  
  // Only run route animation if navigation was imperative (e.g. click)
  if (navigation.navigationTrigger === 'imperative') {
    return outlet && outlet.activatedRouteData && outlet.activatedRouteData['animation'];
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you had the chance to try my solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tricky, but you can.

What you have to do :

- Listen to router events (NavigationEnd)
- When an event happens, check the router state for a boolean
- if the boolean is there, update your animation trigger
- add a state to all of your router links

[Here is a working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-3yh2gx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  animations: [
    trigger('animate', [
      transition('* <=> *', [
        query(':enter', style({ opacity: 0 }), { optional: true }),
        query(':leave', animate('500ms', style({ opacity: 0 })), {
          optional: true,
        }),
        query(':leave', style({ opacity: 0, position: 'absolute' }), {
          optional: true,
        }),
        query(':enter', animate('500ms', style({ opacity: 1 })), {
          optional: true,
        }),
      ]),
    ]),
  ],
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild(RouterOutlet, { static: true }) ro: RouterOutlet;

  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;

  animationTrigger: string;

  get routeState() {
    return this.router.getCurrentNavigation()?.extras?.state;
  }

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private children: ChildrenOutletContexts
  ) {
    router.events
      .pipe(filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd))
      .subscribe((event) => {
        const animate =
          this.router.getCurrentNavigation()?.extras?.state?.animate;

        if (animate)
          // Update the trigger to trigger the animation
          this.animationTrigger = this.ro.activatedRoute.snapshot.data.page;
      });

    timer(5000, 5000).subscribe(() => {
      const url = this.router.url;
      const dest = url === '/hello' ? '/goodbye' : '/hello';
      // Don't send state here = no animation
      this.router.navigateByUrl(dest);
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

```html
<button routerLink="hello" [state]="{ animate: true }">Hello</button> <br />
<button routerLink="goodbye" [state]="{ animate: true }">Goodbye</button>
<br />

animationTrigger : {{ animationTrigger || 'none' }}

<div [@animate]="animationTrigger">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```